# This code works for maze but i dont know how it works. Can somebody explain how does it work that " if" code block?

Tags: c, visual-studio, maze

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int maze1[4][4] = { { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 },  { 0, 1, 0, 0 },  { 1, 1, 1, 1}}; // The maze which is should be solved.

    int maze[4][4];

    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) { //Creating 4*4 matrix
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
            maze[k][l] = 0;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    sol(maze, x, y, maze1);
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
            printf("%3d", maze[k][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

int sol(int maze[4][4], int x, int y, int maze1[4][4]) {
    if (x < 4 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && y < 4 && maze[x][y] == 0 && maze1[x][y] == 1) { 
        maze[x][y] = 1;
        if (x == 3 && y == 3) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (sol(maze, x + 1, y, maze1) == 1) //How does it works ?
            return 0;
        if (sol(maze, x, y + 1, maze1) == 0) // How does it works ?
          return 0;
        else {
            maze[x][y] = 0;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't try to understand strange code you find on the Internet until you're past the beginners stages. Try to implement your assignment yourself to actually learn how to do it and how things work. As for the code you show, do some research about *recursion*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines you marked are simple functions calls. The fact that the function called is the one currently executing is not a problem. This is called a *recursive* function call. You can read about [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) on Wikipedia and elsewhere. The recursive call gets its own parameters and local variables.

For example, say you wanted to calculate the sum of all the non-negative integers up to a given integer. Well, you could define that as follows:

```
int sum_up_to(int i) {
   if (i <= 0)
      return 0;
   else
      return i + sum_up_to(i-1);
}
```

So,

- `sum_up_to(0)` returns `0`.
- `sum_up_to(1)` returns `1 + sum_up_to(0)`, which is `1 + 0`, which is `1`.
- `sum_up_to(2)` returns `2 + sum_up_to(1)`, which is `2 + 1`, which is `3`.
- `sum_up_to(3)` returns `3 + sum_up_to(2)`, which is `3 + 3`, which is `6`.
- `sum_up_to(4)` returns `4 + sum_up_to(3)`, which is `4 + 6`, which is `10`.